# Google maps Iframe and passive listeners

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, iframe

I have an Iframe on my website like below its for the google listing the is for a compay i work for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      <div class="info-section">
        <div class="container foot-container">
          <div class="right d-flex justify-content-center flex-column align-items-center">
            <h4>Where To Find Us</h4>
            <iframe class="my-iframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3030.9233563466883!2d-112.30052128432949!3d40.56536975450923!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8752bd1d6f64f3a5%3A0x2f55c8b8bdbfd4ae!2sWarrior%20Spirit!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1581030992520!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

When I run an audit in the google dev tools I get this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eW8W.png)

When I remove the iframe link and rerun the audit the error is gone.

I have read through a different post about doing {passive: true}.

But I am not exactly sure how to do that with google maps iframe or if it is possible or if there is another soultion to be able to make passive true? Any websites i can visit and read on how to do this will help.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried using your link with a simple code and I don't encounter the error. Can you provide a simple code that shows the error for us to look into it?

Comment: I updated to file to something that produced the error for me when I run an audit in google chrome DevTools.